# Calling only parts of a method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, overloading

If I have a method called

```
-(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha andEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    button.alpha = alpha;
    button.enabled = enabled;    
}
```

Is there anyway I can call only `[self changeButton:buttonName andAlpha:0.5];` and miss out `andEnabled(BOOL)` enabled so that it will stay the same value.

Comment: No.  Create a different method, missing that code out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, only if you declare other methods.

like

```
-(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha {
    [self changeButton:button andAlpha:alpha andEnabled:button.enabled]; 
}

-(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha andEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    button.alpha = alpha;
    button.enabled = enabled;    
}
```

But remember, that this approach is not always good. For example **enabled** property could be backed up by some custom setter which will be called even if you don't want to change that value.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this, you must declare another method.

```
-(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you are asking about default parameterized function of c++.

But Objective-C doesn't support this.

You can create 2 methods though:

```
-(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha {
    button.alpha = alpha; 
}

-(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha andEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    button.alpha = alpha;
    button.enabled = enabled;    
}
```

For C : there's nothing special added to the C subset by using ObjC. Anything that cannot be done in pure C can't be done by compiling in ObjC either. That means, you can't have default parameters, nor overload a function. Create 2 functions instead.

One alternate way(bit lengthy, as someone will use rarely) is to have a flag and check the flag for YES/NO.

```
 -(void) changeButton:(UIButton *)button andAlpha:(float)alpha andEnabled:(BOOL)enabled withFlag:(BOOL)flag{
    button.alpha = alpha;
    if(flag){        
        button.enabled = enabled;    
    }
}
```